# derivative of hadamard product of

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, hadamard-product

I am having difficulties to compute the derivative of the following expression:

$$ (xx^T)\circ A $$

with respect to $x \in R^K $ where $A \in R^{K\times K}$.

Although [Derivative of Hadamard product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773678/derivative-of-hadamard-product) explains derivatives for the Hadamard product of two matrices, I could not extend it to my expression.

Comment: What is $\frac \partial {\partial x_k} x_i x_j a_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a function as $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}, f(x)=(xx^T)\circ A$.

The domain of the function are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and the range of the function are matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$.

We want to evaluate the derivative of the function with respect to $x$. For each entries of the matrix, we can calculate the partial derivative of that entry with respect to the the different entries in the vector $x$. The result can therefore be organized into a 3rd order tensor of dimension $k \times k \times k$ that we can denote by $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ where the partial derivative of the $i,j$ entry of $f(x)$ with respect to $k^{th}$ entry in $x$ is denoted by $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}_{i,j,k}$. We know that the $i,j$ entry of $f(x)_{i,j}=x_ix_ja_{ij}$, so $$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}_{ijk}=\begin{cases}
a_{ij}x_j, s=i\\ 
a_{ij}x_i, s=j\\ 
0 , \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$If the matrices in the equation
$$\eqalign{
F &= A\circ xx^T \\
}$$
are [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) and diagonalized
$$\eqalign{
f &= \vec{F},\qquad a = \vec{A},\qquad Z = \Diag{a} \\
}$$
then calculating derivatives is easy
$$\eqalign{
f &= a\circ\vec{xx^T} \\&= Z\,\vec{xx^T} \\
df &= Z\,\vec{dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T} \\
 &= Z\,\Big((x\otimes I)+(I\otimes x)\Big)\,dx \\
\grad{f}{x} &= Z\,\Big((x\otimes I)+(I\otimes x)\Big) \\
}$$
Or, depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), you may want the transpose of this expression.
$$\\$$

---

Another approach is to use element-wise derivatives.

The key derivative which enables this is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{x}{x_k} &= e_k \\
}$$
where $e_k$ is a standard cartesian basis vector.

Directly differentiating the equation yields
$$\eqalign{
F &= A\circ xx^T \\
\grad{F}{x_k} &= A\circ\LR{e_kx^T+xe_k^T} \\
}$$
Another useful fact is that the $\{e_k\}$ vectors can be distributed over Hadamard products.

This amazing property not shared by any other vector, except (trivially) the zero vector.
$$\eqalign{
{\grad{F_{ij}}{x_k}}
 &= e_i^T\LR{\grad{F}{x_k}}e_j \\
 &= {e_i^TAe_j}\circ\LR{e_i^Te_kx^Te_j+e_i^Txe_k^Te_j} \\
 &= A_{ij} \LR{\delta_{ik}x_j+\delta_{jk}x_i} \\
}$$