# How to calculate the derivative of Fourier transform of a matrix?

Tags: fourier-transform, matrix-calculus

$X$ is a complex matrix and $Y = FT(|X|^2)$, $|X|^2$ stands for elementwise modulus. I want to calculate the derivative of $Y$ to X. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Let $F$ be the DFT matrix, then when you refer to the Fourier transform of a matrix (e.g. $A$), I assume you mean $FAF^*.\;$ Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I think I mean it. I didn't know DFT matrix before and I just searched it. It seems that $FA$ gives Fourier transform of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\p{\partial}$
Your function is
$$Y=F(X^*\circ X)$$
where $X^*$ is the complex conjugate of $X,\,$ and
$(\circ)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Calculate the gradient wrt $X$ in the [CR-Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835) sense, i.e. by treating $X^*$ as independent of $X$
$$\eqalign{
dY &= F(X^*\circ dX) \\
{\rm vec}(dY) &= (I\otimes F)\;{\rm vec}(X^*\circ dX) \\
  &= (I\otimes F)\;\Big({\rm vec}(X^*)\circ{\rm vec}(dX)\Big) \\
  &= (I\otimes F)\cdot{\rm Diag}\Big({\rm vec}(X^*)\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dX) \\
\frac{\p\,{\rm vec}(Y)}{\p\,{\rm vec}(X)}
  &= (I\otimes F)\cdot{\rm Diag}\Big({\rm vec}(X^*)\Big) \\\\
}$$
where $(\otimes)$ denotes the Kronecker product
and the gradient is a second-order tensor (aka a matrix).

The alternative to [vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrices is to [replace the Hadamard product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1963355/357854) with a sixth-order tensor
$$\eqalign{
dY &= F\big(X^*:{\mathbb M}:dX\big) \\
\frac{\p Y}{\p X}
 &= F\big(X^*:{\mathbb M}\big) \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the double-dot product and the gradient is a fourth-order tensor.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanations! It really helps.