# Derivative of Hadamard Product of Hadamard with Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I am stuck at computing the derivative of the following hadamard product:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W} (\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*W) 
$$

W is a random initialized matrix.
I read the post to [Derivative of Hadamard product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773678/derivative-of-hadamard-product) but I still don't understand how to perform the calculation. Do I just have to use the product rule here?

Comment: The Hadamard product is just a product componentwise, so standard differentiation rules apply componentwise.

Answer (score 1):

If we denote $\vec{a}*W$ as the usual product of the vector $\vec{a}$ (writen as a row matrix) and the matrix $W=[w_1,\,w_2,\,\ldots,\, w_n]$, in which $w_i$ is a column vector. Then we can see that $$ (\vec{a}*W)=[\vec{a}*w_1,\,\vec{a}*w_2,\,\ldots,\, \vec{a}*w_n],$$ in which $a*w_i$ is a number.
It follows that
$$f(W)= (\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*W)=[(\vec{a}*w_1)(\vec{b}*w_1),\,(\vec{a}*w_2)(\vec{b}*w_2),\,\ldots,\,(\vec{a}*w_n)(\vec{b}*w_n)],$$ is a row matrix (or a vector).
We can see that $$\frac{\partial (\vec{a}*w_j)(\vec{b}*w_j)}{\partial w_i} =\left\{\begin{array}{rr}(\vec{a}*w_j)\vec{b}+(\vec{b}*w_j)\vec{a},&\quad i=j\\0,&\quad i\neq j\end{array}\right. ,$$ and you can see $$\frac{\partial  (\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*W)}{\partial W}$$ as the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $f(W)$, for instance, when you
identify $W$ and $vec(W)$ (the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of $W$).

You can also see that
$$f(W+H)=f(W)+\left((\vec{a}*H) \circ (\vec{b}*W)+(\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*H)\right)+(\vec{a}*H) \circ (\vec{b}*H),$$ which implies that $$\frac{\partial  (\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*W)}{\partial W}H=(\vec{a}*H) \circ (\vec{b}*W)+(\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*H),$$ when you see $$\frac{\partial  (\vec{a}*W) \circ (\vec{b}*W)}{\partial W}$$ as a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map).

Comment: You can see https://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix#thread_multivar on differentiability in higher dimensions, and find more on SearchOnMath.

Comment: $\def\e{\varepsilon}$Using cartesian basis vectors $\{\e_k\}$ and a diagonalization function, this result can be expressed in terms of its scalar components with respect to those of the $W$ matrix
$${
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial W_{ij}}
 = \e_k^T\,{\rm Diag}(\e_j)\;W^T(ab^T+ba^T)\,\e_i
}$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Assume that $W\in\bbR{m\times n}$ and that $\{e_k,\e_k\}$ are
the standard basis vectors for $\{\bbR{m},\bbR{n}\}$ respectively.
The dimensions of the other vectors in the problem are
$$\eqalign{
a,b\in\bbR{m} \qquad \LR{W^Ta}\in\bbR{n} 
}$$

Now consider the gradient of a small matrix wrt to one of its components.
$$\eqalign{
W &= \m{p&q&r\\x&y&z} \in\bbR{2\times 3} \\
\grad{W}{W_{21}} &= \grad{W}{x} = \m{0&0&0\\1&0&0}
= \m{0\\1}\bullet\m{1&0&0} = e_2\e_1^T \\
}$$
It shouldn't be surprising that in  the general case
$$\eqalign{
\grad{W}{W_{ij}} = e_i\e_j^T \qiq
\grad{W^T}{W_{ij}} = \e_j e_i^T \\
}$$
This result can be applied to differentiate (the transpose of) the current problem.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \c{W^T}b\circ W^Ta &=\; \c{W^T}a\circ W^Tb \\
\grad{f}{W_{ij}}
  &= \c{\e_je_i^T}b\circ W^Ta \;&+\;\c{\e_je_i^T}a \circ W^Tb \\
}$$
Recall the trick for replacing a Hadamard product with a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
a\circ b = \Diag{a}b }$$
and apply it to the gradient expression
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{W_{ij}} &= \Diag{\e_j}\,W^T\!\LR{ab^T+ba^T}e_i \\
}$$
The final step is to isolate the $k^{th}$ component of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f_k}{W_{ij}} &= \e_k^T\gradLR{f}{W_{ij}} 
 &= \e_k^T\Diag{\e_j}\,W^T\!\LR{ab^T+ba^T}e_i \\
}$$
Since this is a scalar, it can be transposed yielding the nice expression
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f_k}{W_{ij}}
 &= e_i^T\LR{ab^T+ba^T}W\,\Diag{\e_j}\,\e_k \\
}$$